# startApp3DBanner display errer in android

Tags: android, xml, startapp

i have add jar file  of start App and build path completely.in 3d banner of start App.

```
    android:id="@+id/startApp3DBanner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/startAppBanner"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="54dp" >
</com.startapp.android.publish.banner.banner3d.Banner3D>
```

main Activity:-

```
StartAppSearch.showSearchBox(this);
    StartAppAd.init(this, "107181003", "211487617");
    StartAppSearch.init(this, "107181003", "211487617");
```

Comment: This is Error :-The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.startapp.android.publish.banner.banner3d.Banner3D (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at com.startapp.android.publish.banner.banner3d.Banner3D.<init>(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at

Comment: sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)

Comment: at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)

Answer (score 0):

Api should Change of Eclipse up to 18 api only not 19 ap.

import startapp .jar and go to project preporty>Java BuildPath>Library>insertLibrary and then Sellect Order and export>then sellect jar move up then fininsh..

Comment: HI Amit I am not getting what Actually is the meaning of sentence. I am also facing same error.

Comment: Would be great if you explain what you have said in your Answer ? Thanks

Comment: your jar file not properly link with project or not proper manner thats by you face this problem ......