# Error at start App 3d Banner in android

Tags: android, xml

This Error comes from my Android App when i insert start app 3d banner:
Error is as follows

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at com.startapp.android.publish.banner.banner3d.Banner3D.<init>(    at com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner.<init>(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [startApp3DBanner display errer in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233306/startapp3dbanner-display-errer-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Api Should change of Eclipse only ......

eclipse api up to 18 not 19

Answer (score 0):

I'm Miki from StartApp.

Please contact our support team through our developers portal or by sending a mail to support@startapp.com.

Please add any extra information that might be helpful - where do you see this error (LogCat? layout graphical editor?), on what device and android version do you get it (if relevant), and also your manifest file.

Thanks

Comment: are you in from startup team member...??