# Google play service ads sdk not working?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I downloaded https://codeload.github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/zip/master It had a sample application for mobile ads. I imported a project in workspace from their sample by clicking import->existing android code in workspace.The problem is the application stops working when run on emulator with android version 3.0
Here is my logcat

```
03-31 20:41:21.601: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(525): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.example.gms.ads.banner/com.google.example.gms.ads.banner.BannerSample}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.y.a(Unknown Source)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ak.an(Unknown Source)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ak.a(Unknown Source)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.google.example.gms.ads.banner.BannerSample.onCreate(BannerSample.java:45)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
03-31 20:41:21.742: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  ... 11 more
```

What is wrong here. I have imported google play services.jar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233306/startapp3dbanner-display-errer-in-android/21234371#21234371

Answer (score 0):

In your android manifest file within `<application>` tag add this :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: It was present there, but eclipse declared it as an error so i had to delete it. Is there any step by step tutorial that i can follow to integrate ads in my application using google play services. I searched a lot but could not find one.

Comment: @user3404195 : Did you check the link?

Comment: yes i checked the link but i had to follow a video on youtube to get it working.

Comment: even am facing same issue. Though i have updated Eclipse Juno

Answer (score 0):

1.Please import Google play service library project in Eclipse (sdk\extras\google\google_play_services).

2.And add this library project to your sample project (right click on your project got to properties->Android-- add library)

3.Clean and build your project.

I hope this work fine.